# How to know a div is fully contain to another

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to identify a one div is fully contain to another ? i have 2 div say A and B . i need to know the A is fully contained inside the B when i dragged to A, and no overlap with A

Comment: Your question is very broad. Please specify what exactly you're having trouble with, supported by perhaps some attempts you've made or research you've done. Simply asking "How do I do this?" without showing an attempt of your own reads very much like you're asking someone to write code for you.

Comment: Can u add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use could use [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for this task.

```js
let options = {
  root: document.querySelector('#container'),
  rootMargin: '0px',
};

let callback = entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 1) {
      console.log("#" + entry.target.id + " is fully inside #container");
    }
    else {
      console.log("#" + entry.target.id + " is NOT fully inside #container");
    }
  });
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
observer.observe(document.querySelector('#inner'));
observer.observe(document.querySelector('#outer'));
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

#inner, #outer {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
}

#outer {
  background: red;
  right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner"></div>
  <div id="outer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I get you right, you can do it manually:

```
// assume you have two elements A and B
var ra = A.getBoundingClientRect();
var rb = B.getBoundingClientRect();
// just check corresponding boundaries 
if (ra.left > rb.left && ra.right < rb.right && ra.top > rb.top && ra.bottom < rb.bottom) { // ... }
```